# Find the finite Fourier sine transform of: $F(x) = x^2$ where $0<x<l$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The question asks:

Find the finite Fourier sine transform of: $F(x) = x^2$ where $0<x<l$.

My tutors solution is simply:
$f_s(n) = \int_{0}^{l}x^2 sin(\frac{\pi n x}{l})dx = \frac{2\pi l^3}{n^3 \pi^3}(cos(n\pi-1)-\frac{l^3}{n\pi}cos(n\pi)$.

Is there some trick that I'm missing? How the hell did he go from that integral to that so quickly - there's so many rules with Fourier transforms, so thats why I ask. So far, I think he just skipped a bunch of steps, which is annoying given I get stuck:

*My workings:*
We have:

$f_s(n) = \int_{0}^{l}x^2 sin(\frac{\pi n x}{l})dx$

let $u = x^2, v = sin(\frac{\pi n x}{l})$ and use integration by parts:

$x^2sin(\frac{\pi n x}{l}) - \int v dv$, where $\frac{dv}{du} = cos(\frac{\pi n - \sqrt{u}}{l}) + \frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}$, and then I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question, we use Integration by parts twice, \begin{matrix}x^2&\sin\dfrac{\pi nx}{l}\\2x&-\dfrac l{\pi n}\cos\dfrac{\pi nx}{l}\\2&-\dfrac{l^2}{\pi^2n^2}\sin\dfrac{\pi nx}{l}\end{matrix}
Therefore the integral is then $$-\dfrac{x^2l}{\pi n}\cos\dfrac{\pi nx}{l}+\dfrac{2xl^2}{\pi^2n^2}\sin\dfrac{\pi nx}{l}\bigg|_0^l-\dfrac{2l^2}{\pi^2n^2}\int_0^l \sin\dfrac{\pi nx}{l}dx$$
The rest should be easy for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the first 3 lines.

Comment: The left column stands for derivatives, and the right column stands for integration, this method applies to the problems which commonly needs several times of IBP. 
Check this link for more information: https://www.mechanicalpeacademy.com/integration-by-parts-the-fast-and-easy-way/
At the 1/3 of the webpage.

Comment: Thank you. Very smart, Kelvin!